# How is filename lookup done in ext4?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, stat, ext4

Env: Linux Kernel 5.3; FS: ext4

When requesting `stat(const char *pathname, struct stat *statbuf)` how is the `const char *pathname` is checked for existence?

It is necessary since in case there is no such path `stat` returns `-1 (ENOENT)`. Here is the program I was testing:

```
static const char *pathname = "/some/fancy/path/name";

int main(void){
    struct stat statbuf;
    unsigned long i = 0;
    int fd = -1;
    while(1){
        if((++i) % 2){
            fd = open(pathname, O_CREAT, 0644);
        }
        stat(pathname, &statbuf);
        if(i % 2){
            close(fd);
            unlink(pathname);
        }
    }
}
```

Every 2 iterations the file was deleted and re-created again on the next one. To inspect kernel call stack I used `perf report`:

[image]

The call stack does not meet my expectation. I expected `ext4` calls under the [`vfs_statx`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/fs/stat.c#L168) in order to traverse `ext4` internal data structures which would probably require disk I/O.

If it was cached in the inode or dentry cache how to flush it in order to inspect what `ext4` calls would require `stat(const char *pathname, struct stat *statbuf);`?

UPD: Taking closer look at the implementation I found that it seems to be taken from dentry cache as specified in the [`link_path_walk`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/fs/namei.c#L2066)

Comment: Take a look at the `path_init` function located at `fs/namei.c`. This function does the checks if the path you are trying to pass starts from root `/` or from the CWD `AT_FDCWD`.  Maybe this can give you some more clue.

Comment: But, your main goal here is to see what `ext4_*` functions are being called, is that correct? Actually I did not understand what you really need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If it was cached in the inode or dentry cache how to flush it in order to inspect what `ext4` calls would require `stat(const char *pathname, struct stat *statbuf);`?

You should be able to do this through `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` (from [`Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt)):

> ```
> drop_caches
>
> Writing to this will cause the kernel to drop clean caches, as well as
> reclaimable slab objects like dentries and inodes.  Once dropped, their
> memory becomes free.
>
> To free pagecache:
>   echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
> To free reclaimable slab objects (includes dentries and inodes):
>   echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
> To free slab objects and pagecache:
>   echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
> ```

Basically just: `echo 2 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.

---

As per the real question, in order to find how ext4 handles lookups, you can look at the `inode_operations` struct [defined in `fs/ext4/namei.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/fs/ext4/namei.c#L4005). More specifically, you are interested in the `.lookup` operation, which is [`ext4_lookup()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/fs/ext4/namei.c#L1675). This function is called when doing lookups.

The call tree should be like this:

- [`link_path_walk()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/fs/namei.c#L2066)

  - [`walk_component()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/fs/namei.c#L1787)

    - [`lookup_slow()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/fs/namei.c#L1679)

      - [`__lookup_slow()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/fs/namei.c#L1640)

        - [`inode->i_op->lookup(...)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/fs/namei.c#L1669) which for ext4 is [`ext4_lookup()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/fs/ext4/namei.c#L1675)

Comment: Nice. I also reached to the point of `i_op->lookup()`, but for some reason looked at [`ext4_file_inode_operations`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/fs/ext4/file.c#L529) which does not have `lookup` initialized. I just realized that `lookup` operation does not make sense for a regular file though.